# Smart Array P410: Can't get drives recognized on port 2i

Tags: hp-proliant

I have an HP ProLiant DL380 G7 with a standard 8SFF drive cage attached to the internal p410i card, and an additional 8SFF drive cage attached to a second p410 card. The first array/card/cage works fine. The second array/card/cage detects only the drives on Port 1I. The status of the drives in bay 5-8 show as "fault" in iLO. The drives in those bays work fine if moved into bay 1-4. Bay 5-8 shows solid amber lights.

I've updated all the firmware to the latest version, but still no movement on this. I can't even find anything that indicates the issue beyond "fault." Any ideas? Thanks!

This question: [Smart Array P600: Can't get drives recognized on port 2i](https://serverfault.com/questions/328630/smart-array-p600-cant-get-drives-recognized-on-port-2i)

is very similar to my issue, but was never answered.

Comment: When did this happen?  Have you just added the second controller and cage?  What happens if you connect the cages to the other controllers, this will help you identify any faulty hardware, no?

Comment: It happened as soon as they were installed/on boot. I haven't had a chance to try the second cage on the internal controller yet, but I'll try that next.